# Finding relationship between solutions of two different first order linear PDEs (using Feynman-Kac)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-pde

The first partial differential equation, using the shorthand $\mathcal{L}u(t,x) = \mu(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t) + \tfrac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x,t)$, is: 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mathcal{L}u(x,t) -Vu(x,t) + f(x,t) = 0
\tag{1}\end{equation}

and the other is 
\begin{equation} 
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(x,t) + \mathcal{L}v(x,t) -(V + W)* v(x,t) + f(x,t) = 0
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

both with terminal condition: $v(T,x) = u(T,x) = g(x)$ and with constants $V$ and $W$.

So the only difference is that the second equation has the term $-Wv(x,t)$ included. I want to find out how I can relate the two solutions, so that if I have a solution of $(1)$ I can multiply it by something and get a solution of $(2)$.

I am wondering if this is possible. So far, I have written, using Feynman-Kac, solutions to both equations:

\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = E^Q\left[ \int_t^T e^{-V (r-t)}f(X_r,r)dr + e^{-V(T-t)}g(X_T) \Bigg| X_t=x \right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
v(x,t) = E^Q\left[ \int_t^T e^{-(V +G) (r-t)}f(X_r,r)dr + e^{-(V+G)(T-t)}g(X_T) \Bigg| X_t=x \right]
\end{equation}

I can't seem to think of a way to connect the two together, but according to a book I'm reading there should be a way to do this (but there's no other details). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the stochastic PDE in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $u$ and $v$ solve
$$
\left[\partial_{t}+\mathcal{L}-c\right]u+f=0
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\left[\partial_{t}+\mathcal{L}-\left(c+d\right)\right]v+e^{dt}f=0.
$$
Moreover, suppose $u(T,\cdot)=g$ and $v(T,\cdot)=e^{dT}g$. If we
assume enough regularity on $u$ and $v$ along with $\mu$, $\sigma$,
and $g$, the Feynman-Kac formula tells us that
$$
u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{T}e^{-c(r-t)}f(r,X_{r})dr+e^{-c\left(T-t\right)}g(X_{T})\mid X_{t}=x\right]
$$
and
\begin{align*}
v(t,x) & =\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{T}e^{-(c+d)(r-t)}e^{dr}f(r,X_{r})dr+e^{-(c+d)(T-t)}e^{dT}g(X_{T})\right]\\
 & =\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{t}^{T}e^{-c(r-t)}f(r,X_{r})dr+e^{-c(T-t)}g(X_{T})\right]e^{dt}\\
 & =e^{dt}u(t,x)
\end{align*}
where $X$ satisfies an Ito SDE with infinitesimal generator $\mathcal{L}$

Are you sure this is not what you/the text meant?

**Note**: a simpler argument to go from one PDE to the other is by a change of variables.

Comment: This was it! Thanks a lot! The text was unclear so I didn't realize the $f$ term could be adjusted as well. Can you elaborate on the change of variables method? Is it just using $\left[\partial_{t}+\mathcal{L}-\left(c+d\right)\right]v+e^{dt}f=0$ with $v = e^{dt}u(t,x)$ and then expanding out $\partial_{t}v = \partial_{t}e^{dt}u = \partial_{t}u * e^{dt} + d*e^{dt}u$, and so this results in $\left[\partial_{t}+\mathcal{L}-c\right]u+f=0$ when dividing out $e^{dt}$. (Or doing the reverse by multiplying the $u$ equation by $e^{dt}$.)

Comment: That's right (+1). If $u$ is a $C^{1,2}$ solution of the first PDE, then you can define $v \equiv e^{dt} u$ to be a solution of the second. Vice versa, if $v$ is a $C^{1,2}$ solution of the second PDE, you can define $u \equiv e^{-dt} v$ as a solution of the first.

Comment: Nit: Try not to use $*$ to mean multiplication. This operator is commonly used for convolutions.